# How do I build wall-mounted shelves?

Tags: carpentry, storage, joinery

I've spent the past few months getting my flat renovated, and would now like to build some bookshelves across two of the walls in my living room, and around the corner that joins these walls.

The walls are each around 3000mm long, and the ceiling height is 2700mm. I have a corner sofa that runs along the walls, and I'd like the bookshelves to only cover the area of the walls above the sofa. One of the walls is an old lathe and plaster with stone behind it; the other wall is brick. I'd like the sofas to be as close to the wall as possible, so I'm guessing that the weight of the shelves (and contents) can't really be supported by the floor.

What's the best way to build these shelves? I have some timber that's been removed from my flat during the renovation that I'd like to use, but I don't mind buying new materials if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthias Wandel has a great article (and plans) for making shelving units: http://woodgears.ca/shelves/

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution. Similar to how I had some temporary shelves in my flat before, but those ones had extra supports running down the front of the shelves.